# Overriding list method

Tags: python

I'm trying to override a list method and append 2 elements. How can I do that?

```
class LI(list):
    def append(self, item):
        self.append(item)


l = LI([100, 200])
l.append(302)
l.append(402)

print l
```

Final output:

```
[100,200,302,302,402,402]
```

Comment: Perhaps you were looking for `list.extend`?

Comment: This code goes into infinite recursion.

Comment: To avoid recursion, call `super(LI, self).append(item)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class LI(list):
    def append(self, *args):
        self.extend(args)
```

Now you can use it:

```
a = LI()
a.append(1,2,3,4)
a.append(5)
```

Or maybe you meant:

```
class LI(list):
    def append(self, item):
        list.append(self,item)
        list.append(self,item)
```

But really, why not just use a regular list and `extend` and `append` the way they were meant to be used?

```
a = list()
a.extend((1,2,3,4))
a.append(5)
```

or

```
a = list()
item = 1
a.extend((item,item))
```